# What is the most efficient way to implement NestPairWhileList[f,expr,test,g]

Tags: iteration, functional-style

### Question

`NestWhileList[f,x,test]` lets you iterate a function until a condition is satisfied, outputting the list of iterated values

```
    In[1]:= NestWhileList[f,x,test]

    Out[1]:= {x,f[x],f[f[x]],f[f[f[x]]], ... }
```

If the objects produced `Nest[f,x,n]` are large, and require a lot of storage space, and one only requires some small amount of data captured by `g[Nest[f,x,n]]`, one would like a function

```
    In[2]:= NestPairWhileList[f,x,test,g]

    Out[2]:= {g[x],g[f[x]],g[f[f[x]]],g[f[f[f[x]]]], ... }
```

is there a simple and efficient way to implement this operation?

This is similar to the relationship between `FoldList` and `FoldPairList`, but without requiring the a priori knowledge of the number of iterations.

### Naive guess at answer

I can see that one can do

```
    In[3]:= NestPairWhileList[f_, x_, test_, g_] := g/@NestWhileList[f,x,test]
```

to produce the correct output, but I do not expect this to be memory efficient as it requires producing the entire output of `NestWhileList`.

Comment: perhaps `nPWL1[f_, x_, test_, g_] := 
 Reap[NestWhileList[Sow@f[##] &, x, test], _, g /@ #2 &][[2]]`?

Comment: ... or `nPWL2[f_, x_, test_, g_] := 
 Reap[NestWhileList[(Sow[g[#]]; #) &@f[##] &, x, test]][[2]]`?

Answer (score 2):

The function

```
    In[4]:= NestPairWhileList[f_, x_, test_, g_] := ...

        ... Join[#[[1, 1]],{#[[2]]}]&@Reverse@Reap@g@NestWhile[(Sow[g[#]]; f[#]) &, x, test]
```

seems to return the right results. Though maybe there are better ways to do this.